# BIRT Report using POJOs unning under tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, birt

This is my first time when I use BIRT engine. I focused with problem using POJOs.

I have simple POJO:

```
class Parent {
  private String name;
  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

And simple BIRT report which only prints Parent name (I print name only for 1 Parent, it means - I send a list only with 1 records).

I successfully generate PDF with Parent name using JUnit tests, while when I try to generate it in Tomcat - BIRT doesn't insert values from POJO.

Have you ever focused with this problem?

Birt wrapper class:

```
public class BirtRenderer implements IBirtRenderer {

    private EngineConfig config;
    private IReportEngine engine;
    private IReportEngineFactory factory;

    public BirtRenderer() throws BirtException {
        config = new EngineConfig();
        config.setLogConfig("J:\\BirtLogs", Level.WARNING);

        // config.setLogger(new Log4jHandler());

        Platform.startup(config);

        factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
        engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        engine.destroy();
        Platform.shutdown();
    }

    public ByteArrayOutputStream executeReport(String reportName, String fileFormat, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map context) throws EngineException {
        return executeReport(reportName, fileFormat, context, Locale.US);
    }

    public ByteArrayOutputStream executeReport(String reportName, String fileFormat, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map context, Locale locale) throws EngineException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        reportName = reportName + ".rptdesign";

        /* for testing */
        context = new HashMap();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new TitleCustomerDao().next());
        context.put("APP_CONTEXT_KEY_TITLE_CUSTOMER_DATA", list);
        /* for testing end */

        InputStream reportStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);

        if (reportStream == null)
            throw new EngineException(new BirtException("File '" + reportName + "' was not found."));

        // Open the report design
        IReportRunnable design = null;
        // design =
        // engine.openReportDesign("J:/birt-workspace/test/hello_world.rptdesign");
        design = engine.openReportDesign(reportStream);
        IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
        // task.setParameterValue("Top Count", (new Integer(5)));
        // task.validateParameters();

        RenderOption renderOption = getRenderOption(fileFormat);
        renderOption.setOutputStream(outputStream);

        task.setRenderOption(renderOption);
        // task.setParameterValue("APP_CONTEXT_KEY_PARENTS", data);
        task.setAppContext(context);
        if (locale != null)
            task.setLocale(locale);

        if (!task.validateParameters()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters do not validate");
        }

        task.run();
        task.close();

        return outputStream;
    }

    private RenderOption getRenderOption(String fileFormat) {
        if (fileFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
            PDFRenderOption PDF_OPTIONS = new PDFRenderOption();
            // PDF_OPTIONS.setOutputFileName("J:/birt-workspace/test/hello_world.pdf");
            PDF_OPTIONS.setOutputFormat("pdf");

            return PDF_OPTIONS;
        } else if (fileFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("html")) {
            HTMLRenderOption HTML_OPTIONS = new HTMLRenderOption();
            // HTML_OPTIONS.setOutputFileName("J:/birt-workspace/test/hello_world.html");
            HTML_OPTIONS.setOutputFormat("html");

            return HTML_OPTIONS;
        } else
            return null;

    }

}
```

After long investigation I found where is the problem.

The problem is that I use Apache FOP library in the same web project, where I use BIRT.
If we will go to the details - the problem is with Apache Batik library, which is used by Apache FOP 1.0 (uses >=1.7 Batik) & BIRT 4.4.2 (uses 1.6).

And it is really strange why BIRT Runtime Java library inside overrides Batik groupIds and artifacts.

Do you have any suggestion how is it possible to use Apache FOP & BIRT 4.4.2 Runtime Java library in the same web project?

It also depends on, which dependency do you specify on top.

Using this POM.XML PDF report is generated successfully and all POJO data is binded correctly:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
<version>4.4.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
<artifactId>fop</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Using this POM.XML PDF report is rendered with empty POJO data fields:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It is likely to be a classpath issue, where did you put the jar containing this pojo in Tomcat? Where is the code running the report: is it in the same webapp as the birt engine or in a separate web application?

Comment: This POJO & BIRT engine wrapper jar (used to create engine & configure it) goes in WEB-INF\lib forlder. The data comes from controllers, which are placed in WEB-INF\classes.

Comment: Can you show the code creating & configuring the BIRT engine? I think i know why it does not work but i want to  be sure

Comment: Dominique, I just added source code of BIRT Renderer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a problem.

The problem was with Java libraries. Apache FOP uses Apache Batik, which has an artifact batik-js. This is a bottle neck, because BIRT Runtime library uses newer version.

It was very hard to find a problem, because BIRT Runtime uses "org.mozilla.javascript-1.7.2.jar" while FOP uses "batik-js-1.7.jar". Both of them stores the same Java classes.

So Java ClassLoader took older version (FOP version) of jar, when we specify FOP dependency on TOP.

It's still a question - why BIRT Runtime developers created different maven artifacts with the same Java classes.

So my new pom.xml is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>batik-js</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

I think your POJO does not work in Tomcat because you forgot to provide a classloader to the BIRT engine. Try to add this:

```
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConstants;
```

and in your constructor:

```
config.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_CLASSLOADER_KEY, BirtRenderer.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: I am sorry to notice you, but it doesn't make any effect. I tried many various options, also I tried to add class loader into the context in executeReport method. It doesn't solve problem.

Comment: What about the logs of the birt engine, is there any clue?

Comment: BIRT log files are empty in WARNING level.